# How to synchronize between executors of an ExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.concurrent

I have a list of client sockets, usually of size around 2000. These clients are dynamic, they come and go.

I have an `ExecutorService` with a fixed thread pool of 32 threads handling these threads. This executor service is responsible for decoding and sending the messages to be sent to these 2000 clients.

I want to prevent that two (or more) threads of the executor service are processing the same client at the same time.

One approach could be to introduce another *bookkeeping thread* (so I end up with 32 + 1 threads) which is responsible for calling `ExecutorService.submit(mesage)` when the previous message corresponding to the same client is done. But I am not sure if this will introduce a bottleneck, meaning that this newly introduced *bookkeeping thread* cannot keep up submitting messages.

Ideally, I don't want to pre-allocate a thread to a set of clients in advance, as the message load is not evenly distributed between the clients. It is also not known in advance.

What are approaches for this? Are they offered by `java.util.concurrent` functionalities?

**update**

This is a quick summary, as the comments pointed out that there were some misunderstandings:

- I don't want a single thread per client, as I would end up with 2000 threads.
- Ideally, I don't want to pre-allocate a thread to a set of clients, because message rate is not evenly distributed between all clients and not known in advance.
- Message order must be preserved.
- I believe it would not be good that thread `A` is waiting for thread `B` because `B` is already sending a message to the same client. In other words, at all times only one thread is processing one client.

Comment: "I want to prevent that two (or more) threads of the executor service are processing the same client at the same time." don't understand that requirement. Does it happen that you have 2 jobs for the same client concurrently? Why is that a problem?

Comment: I think he want to serialize processing requests from the same origin. Dunno why

Comment: The client socket can only be used by one single thread at the same time, it's not thread-safe. In addition, the messages for a client must be sent in correct sequence order.

Comment: Insteed of serializing threads, serialize socket write.

Comment: Isn't that sub-optimal, as a number of threads might be waiting for the lock guarding the socket held by one thread? Also, how do we preserve message ordering in this approach?

Comment: Its abnormal to do what you are trying to do anyway.

Comment: Using concurrent queue. Queues can be ordered as well if that is required for some reasons

Comment: What's abnormal about it? I have `x` clients and `y` threads responsible for sending messaging to these clients.

Comment: In case you've just started the project, the [netty.io](http://netty.io/) library solves many issues like that quite nicely. Otherwise, think about a fixed thread per client, have it referenced by the client so you can enqueue tasks for a specific thread. Blocking queues and consumers maybe.

Comment: I don't like the fixed-thread-per-client approach, as I would end up with 2000 threads. I want 32 threads responsible for sending messages, while preserving message order and avoiding that thread `A` must wait for thread `B` because `B` is already sending a message to the same client.

Comment: Sounds like the simplest approach is to synchronize on the socket object.

Comment: Use a Queue where all Threads are consumers and get a next object from it (also, at this point, if no clients are available you can already make the Thread wait until data is available), this way you don't need to submit Tasks for the Executor and keep all threads running full time

Comment: A queue also have the benefit for keeping message order

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos And how do we preserve message order in that approach? It can happen that both thread `A` and `B` take message `1` and `2` but due to thread scheduling, message `2` will be sent first.

Comment: Every new message you add to the Queue, every Thread when available will request the Queue for the latest message, the queue returns it and remove from its pool.

Comment: Ohhh... got your problem, you will need a lock based on clients then

Comment: Exactly my thought :). But it would be bad if several threads are waiting for the same lock.

Comment: No need for waiting, all 32 threads can be kept busy, and message order can be retained, on a per-client basis. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51849785/5221149).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a thread (A) begins processing a message (#1), it needs to register the client id with a shared manager object. For each registered client, there is a queue.

When another thread (B) begins processing a message (#2) for the same client, the registration will detect that thread A is already processing, and will add message #2 to the queue for client. Thread B will then stop and process the next message.

When thread A is done with message #1, it will try to unregister, but since message #2 is queue, thread A will instead begin processing that message. After that, when it tries to unregister again, there are no queued messages and the thread will stop and process the next message.

It is up to the manager code to correctly synchronize access, so a second message is either processed by thread B, or handed off to thread A, without getting lost.

The above logic ensures that thread B will not wait for thread A, i.e. no idle time, and that message #2 is processed as soon as possible, i.e. with minimal delay, without processing two messages for the same client as the same time.

Message order *for each client* is retained. Globally, message order is of course not retained, because the processing of message #2 is delayed.

Note, there will be only one queue for each thread, so only 32 queues, and only "duplicate" messages are queue, so all queue will usually remain empty.

---

**UPDATE**

Example: For identification here, messages are named `clientId.messageId` where `messageId` is global.

Messages are submitted to the Executor (3 threads) in this order:

`1.1, 2.2, 1.3, 2.4, 3.5, 1.6`

1. Thread A picks up `1.1` and starts processing.
2. Thread B picks up `2.2` and starts processing.
3. Thread C picks up `1.3`, adds it to thread A's queue, then returns.
4. Thread C picks up `2.4`, adds it to thread B's queue, then returns.
5. Thread C picks up `3.5` and starts processing.
6. Thread A is done with message `1.1` and starts processing `1.3`.
7. Thread C is done with message `3.5` and returns.
8. Thread C picks up `1.6`, adds it to thread A's queue, then returns.
   Thread C is now idle.
9. Thread B is done with message `2.2` and starts processing `2.4`.
10. Thread A is done with message `1.3` and starts processing `1.6`.
11. Thread B is done with message `2.4` and returns.
     Thread B is now idle.
12. Thread A is done with message `1.6` and returns.
     Thread A is now idle.

Comment: I think there is one disadvantage to this approach: if there is a high message rate, we might end up in a situation where the 32 threads prioritizing the same 32 clients over and over again (as after each message, another message is ready to be sent), meaning that the other 2000 - 32 clients are effectively starving, if that makes sense.

Comment: @IsaacVero That is the way it *should* be, because original global message order says that those messages should already have been processed, so they get priority. Extra logic can be added to begin discarding messages if a client cannot keep up (i.e. too many messages in registration queue for the client), but rules for that needs to be defined by OP, if it's needed.

Comment: Let me rephrase, maybe I misunderstood. Thread `A` is sending a message to client `1`. During that, two messages are added: a message for client `2` and also another message for client `1`. If I understood correctly, your approach is that thread `A` immediately processes the second message for `1` after the first message, instead of the message for client `2`. Now assume a high message rate. I believe this means that we are prioritizing the same clients over and over again, and starving the other ones?

Comment: Also, I understand that there are 32 threads and 32 queues. So each thread is doing `while(true) { process(queue.take()); }`? So **who** decides on **which** queue a new message should be added?

Comment: @IsaacVero No. There are 33 queues: The Executor queue, and 32 "delayed message" queues, one for each thread. Messages are submitted to the Executor, which delegates them to threads for processing as the threads become available. If executor honors submit order, this ensures that global message order is preserved. If a "duplicate" message is picked up by a thread, the message is added to the "delayed message" queue of the thread current processing a message for the given client. *That* thread will immediate process the delayed message when done with the first message.

Comment: @IsaacVero Your entire question is about how to delay processing of secondary messages to the client, *because* ExecutorService can't do it. This is one way to handle that limitation of ExecutorService. --- The logic described here doesn't add any extra threads. "An ExecutorService with a fixed thread pool of 32 threads" will have the threads.

Comment: @IsaacVero You should **read the documentation**, i.e. the javadoc of [`Executors.newFixedThreadPool(int nThreads)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool-int-): *"Creates a thread pool that reuses a fixed number of threads operating off a **shared unbounded queue**. [...] If additional tasks are submitted when all threads are active, they will **wait in the queue** until a thread is available"*. Queues maintain order.

Comment: @IsaacVero I don't know how the ExecutorService delegates tasks to the threads of the thread pool. That's internal, and doesn't matter to this.

Comment: I have nothing more to say.

Comment: Fair enough. Thank you for your explanations, the idea of introducing a queue for duplicate messages is clever.

Answer (score 0):

Have each thread service it's own queue. Number the sockets. Put each request on queue[socket num % num of threads].

This will ensures requests from a particular socket are handled in series and in sequence.

Unfortunately you won't get load balancing this way.

Alternatively, use a concurrenthashmap to store the sockets being served. If a thread services a request of a socket currently being processed, just put the request back in the queue.

Comment: Why the down vote, can you explain why this answer is incorrect ?

Comment: There's no thread per client, message order is preserved and there is no explicit blocking.

Comment: I did not down vote your question (I don't have enough reputation for that), but I have a hard time understanding what you meant in that last sentence. Maybe you could elaborate?

Comment: @IsaacVero what I imagine this could look like: https://gist.github.com/zapl/62d6af5e7dde5cc209c058313ca7ed16

Comment: Got it, thank you. This approach makes sense if we have an evenly distributed load, which is not the case here. Now, you might end up in the situation that just one thread is doing all the work. Maybe that's why it is downvoted?

Comment: @IsaacVero Don't think so. Downvote is most likely for shorter, not so nice looking answer (initially). And if there is only 1 client active, due to your ordering requirements, there can't be more than 1 thread active. Happens in either solution. The other one is a little more dynamic when it comes to uneven load between just a few clients but I doubt this would actually be a real world problem. The distribution between 2k clients should even out over 32 threads fairly well. This is also what netty does, a fixed binding between thread and client, and they are the #1 network framework for java.

Comment: That's interesting to know (about netty), thank you for adding that. In my case, the *weight* of each client can differ quite dramatically (some clients require more messages due to their characteristics), so it might make sense to try to avoid a fixed assignment between thread and client. I will have to benchmark that though. That said, it's interesting to know that netty spreads out the clients evenly over the available threads (under the implicit assumption that each client has the same *weight*), so we can assume that that would be the *default* implementation for this kind of question.

Answer (score 0):

You want to process messages for each client sequentially and at the same time you do not want to allocate separate thread for each client. This is the exact use case to employ [Actor model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model). Actors are like lightweight threads. They are not as powerful as the usual threads but fit ideally for repeatable tasks like yours.
If you find `java actor libraries` found by Google too heavyweight, you can use the [most compact actor implementation](https://github.com/akaigoro/CodeSamples/blob/master/src/simpleactor/SimpleActor.java) at my Github repository, or look at the extended actor implementation included in my asynchronous library `df4j`.